# javascript: optional first argument in function

Tags: javascript

I have a typical javascript function with some parameters

```
my_function = function(content, options) { action }
```

if I call the function as such :

```
my_function (options)
```

the argument "options" is passed as "content"

how do i go around this so I can either have both arguments passed or just one ?
thank you

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You have to decide as which parameter you want to treat a single argument. You cannot treat it as both, `content` and `options`.

I see two possibilities:

1. Either change the order of your arguments, i.e. `function(options, content)`
2. Check whether `options` is defined:

   ```
   function(content, options) {
       if(typeof options === "undefined") {
           options = content;
           content = null;
       }
       //action
   }
   ```

   But then you have to document properly, what happens if you only pass one argument to the function, as this is not immediately clear by looking at the signature.

Comment: undefined is a global property with a constant value, as such you don't need to quote it. In obsolete browsers you could accidentally set it to an arbitrary value, but this is not the case of modern-day browsers.

Comment: @Andrew: `typeof` always returns a string. Alternatively, `if (options === undefined)` would work as well. But as you said, it is possible to override `undefined` in older browsers, so still prevalent practice (I think) is to not directly use `undefined` (unless you defined somewhere explicitly).

Comment: do not compare strings with `===`, those are not necessairy the same Object if thy have the same content.

Comment: @inetphantom: not sure what you are saying. That doesn't make sense. Primitive strings are not objects anyway.

Comment: if you know that `content` and `options` will NOT be of the same type you can check for type of `content` and swap if need be.    I also see people counting arguments to do this.  Checking `content` instead of `options`  also provides some additional argument validation

Answer (score 30):

```
my_function = function(hash) { /* use hash.options and hash.content */ };
```

and then call:

```
my_function ({ options: options });
my_function ({ options: options, content: content });
```

Comment: @Muneer: It is just an example.

Comment: Sure sign of a ruby background.

Comment: @FrontierPsycho Or Perl.

Comment: @BlueBird hash is just referring to a hash table (aka dictionary / associative array) which Darin is equating to a Javascript object.

Answer (score 22):

Like this:

```
my_function (null, options) // for options only
my_function (content) // for content only
my_function (content, options) // for both
```

Answer (score 16):

With ES6:

```js
function test(a, b = 3) {
   console.log(a, b);
}

test(1);      // Output: 1 3
test(1, 2);   // Output: 1 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you also can differentiate by what type of content you got. Options used to be an object the content is used to be a string, so you could say:

```
if ( typeof content === "object" ) {
  options = content;
  content = null;
}
```

Or if you are confused with renaming, you can use the arguments array which can be more straightforward:

```
if ( arguments.length === 1 ) {
  options = arguments[0];
  content = null;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this variation: 

`var optional_arg = arguments.length >= 1 ? arguments[0] : 'default value';`

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice read on Default parameters in ES6 [on the MDN website here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). 
In ES6 you can now do the following:

```
secondDefaultValue = 'indirectSecondDefaultValue';

function MyObject( param1 = 'firstDefaultValue', param2 = secondDefaultValue ){
    this.first = param1;
    this.second = param2;
}
```

You can use this also as follows:

```
var object = new MyObject( undefined, options );
```

Which will set default value `'firstDefaultValue'` for first `param1` and your `options` for second `param2`.

[Here a demonstration in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/ty7p52qz/)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1)

```
function something(options) {
    var timeToLive = options.timeToLive || 200; // default to 200 if not set
    ...
}
```

2)

```
function something(timeToDie /*, timeToLive*/) {
    var timeToLive = arguments[1] || 200; // default to 200 if not set
    ..
}
```

In 1), `options` is a JS object with what ever attributes are required. This is easier to maintain and extend.

In 2), the function signature is clear to read and understand that a second argument can be provided. I've seen this style used in Mozilla code and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple library for handling optional arguments with JavaScript functions, see https://github.com/ovatto/argShim. The library is developed with Node.js in mind but should be easily ported to work with e.g. browsers.

Example:

```
var argShim = require('argShim');
var defaultOptions = {
  myOption: 123
};

var my_function = argShim([
    {optional:'String'},
    {optional:'Object',default:defaultOptions}
  ], function(content, options) {
    console.log("content:", content, "options:", options);
  });

my_function();
my_function('str');
my_function({myOption:42});
my_function('str', {myOption:42});
```

Output:

```
content: undefined options: { myOption: 123 }
content: str options: { myOption: 123 }
content: undefined options: { myOption: 42 }
content: str options: { myOption: 42 }
```

The main target for the library are module interfaces where you need to be able to handle different invocations of exported module functions.

Comment: This is very verbose, plus it uses the word "default" which is already a keyword in JS. Would not recommend.

Comment: Sure it may be a bit verbose but it does provide some added features on top of simple argument presence checking. And writing same features in each function is bound to be even more verbose. Also while some don't like it reserved keywords can freely be used as property names in ES5. However the whole lib was pretty hastily written so your (and mine) mileage may vary :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all your optional arguments in an object as the first argument. The second argument is your callback. Now you can accept as many arguments as you want in your first argument object, and make it optional like so:

```
function my_func(op, cb) {
    var options = (typeof arguments[0] !== "function")? arguments[0] : {},
        callback = (typeof arguments[0] !== "function")? arguments[1] : arguments[0];

    console.log(options);
    console.log(callback);
}
```

If you call it without passing the options argument, it will default to an empty object:

```
my_func(function () {});
=> options: {}
=> callback: function() {}
```

If you call it with the options argument you get all your params:

```
my_func({param1: 'param1', param2: 'param2'}, function () {});
=> options: {param1: "param1", param2: "param2"}
=> callback: function() {}
```

This could obviously be tweaked to work with more arguments than two, but it get's more confusing. If you can just use an object as your first argument then you can pass an unlimited amount of arguments using that object. If you absolutely need more optional arguments (e.g. my_func(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg10, fn)), then I would suggest using a library like [ArgueJS](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJs). I have not personally used it, but it looks promising.

Comment: thanks a lot... Exactly I'm searching for this. I have a 6 parameters in my function. some parameters have a default values. But some parameters should set in function call. I think this answer will well suited to my case. Thanks again... :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to kick a long-dead horse, because I've had to implement an optional argument in the middle of two or more required arguments. Use the `arguments` array and use the *last* one as the required non-optional argument.

```
my_function() {
  var options = arguments[argument.length - 1];
  var content = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[0] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the un passed argument value as undefined. 
But in your case you have to pass at least null value in the first argument.

Or you have to change the method definition like

```
my_function = function(options, content) { action }
```

Answer (score -1):

Call like this

```
my_function ("", options);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also put a check in the action like:
`options = !options ? content : options`
that sets options to the first argument if no second was passed in, and then you just set content to null (or ignore it, however you want to check that)