# Multiple optional parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a function as below

```
function addressCombo(street1:string, street2:string = "NA", street3?:string) {
    console.log("street1: " + street1);
    console.log("street1: " + street2);
    console.log("street2: " + street3);
}
```

And I want to pass values for parameter `street1` and `street3` but not `street2` then how can I do that?

I am from `C#` background and we do it as below

```
addressCombo("ABC", street3 : "XYZ");
```

Comment: I wish it worked more like C#, it seems weird that you can make a function have an optional parameter but you still have to pass it an undefined value for each optional parameter anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an object to pass your parameters (or something like `streets: { [key: string]: string }`):

```
function addressCombo({street1, street2, street3}: { street1?: string; street2?: string; street3?: string } = {}) {
  console.log("street1: " + street1);
  console.log("street2: " + street2);
  console.log("street3: " + street3);
}

addressCombo()
// Log:
// street1: undefined
// street2: undefined
// street3: undefined

addressCombo({ street1: 'A', street2: 'B', street3: 'C' });
// Log:
// street1: A
// street2: B
// street3: C

addressCombo({ street1: 'A', street3: 'C' });
// Log:
// street1: A
// street2: undefined
// street3: C
```

Answer (score 15):

This is not really a TypeScript question but a JavaScript question.

Optional parameters must be at the back and can only be left out if all later arguments are left out as well. Otherwise JavaScript doesn't know for which parameter you passed a value.

Consider the second parameter in your example is optional. In a call you would just leave it out and not pass a value.

```
function addressCombo(street1, street2, street3) {}

addressCombo("LA", "LO")
```

However JavaScript doesn't know that you intended `"LO"` to be the argument for `street3` and not `street2`. Instead it will assign them in the row.

In other words, you can't have an argument for `street3` after you left out `street2`.

What you could to is explicitly pass `undefined` to the optional parameters, which is what would happen anyway if you left an argument out. In your example this would be

```
addressCombo("LA", undefined, "LO")
```

Please see also

[Skip arguments in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518615/skip-arguments-in-a-javascript-function)

[javascript: optional first argument in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147640/javascript-optional-first-argument-in-function)

[How to pass optional parameters while omitting some other optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734509/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-while-omitting-some-other-optional-parameters)

Comment: Both the answers work for me, but I think the accepted one is more flexible. If the number of such parameters grows passing `undefined` will be hard and a bit ugly. +1 though.